# No job functions found in Azure Webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

Trying to get Azure Webjobs to react to incoming Service Bus event, Im running this by hitting F5. Im getting the error at startup.

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers,
>   etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(),
>   config.UseTimers(), etc.).

My functions-class look like this:

```
   public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("test-from-dynamics-queue")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

I have every class and method set to public

I am calling  `config.UseServiceBus();` in my **program.cs** file

Im using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v 1.1.2

((Im not entirely sure I have written the correct AzureWebJobsDashboard- and AzureWebJobsStorage-connectionstrings, I took them from my only Azure storage-settings in Azure portal. If that might be the problem, where should I get them ))

Comment: can you also post program source?

Comment: definitely need to see how you're setting up the service bus config

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to your mentioned error, it seems that  you miss parameter config for ininitializing JobHost. If it is that case, please use the following code.

```
JobHost  host = new JobHost(config)
```

More detail info about how to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK please refer to the document.The following is the sample code from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus).

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
      config.UseServiceBus();
      JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
      host.RunAndBlock();
   }
}
```

Comment: Right on the money! Thanks! Was too tired lat night from banging my head against the (azure functions) wall.

Comment: I just created a new webjob project which used the visual studio 2015 template - and it had var host = new JobHost(); i.e. no (config) ...not very helpful!

Comment: Thanks alot man, This has kiilled my day. Could not find this in the documentation.There is lot of redundant content in the internet. Couldnt believe people are copy pasting blogs as well.

Comment: The template from Visual Studio should *probably* take care of this for you - Tom can you escalate and have this addressed to save some manhours (and hair)?

Comment: Thank you! I could not find this documented anywhere as well.